# Tangent Space in $S^{n-1}$ and Orthogonal Stiefel Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential

In chapter 3 of [this book](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/absil/Absil_Chap3.pdf), it is stated that tangent space $T_x\mathcal{M}$ of a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ can be found using the relation
$$ T_x\mathcal{M} = \text{ker}(DF(x)) $$, if $\mathcal{M}$ is defined using a a level set of constant rank using the function $F: \mathcal{E} \to \Bbb{R}^n$

While I intuitively understand this relation, I am confused with the math in the examples.

E.g. Tangent to a sphere $S^{n-1}$ is given as follows:
$$
T_{x} S^{n-1}=\operatorname{ker}(\operatorname{DF}(x))=\left\{z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: x^{T} z+z^{T} x=0\right\}=\left\{z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: x^{T} z=0\right\}
$$

I specifically do not understand how they obtained this term $x^{T} z+z^{T} x=0$; My understanding of $DF(x)$ is as follows: $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}, \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_2},\dots \right)$ dot product with the coefficients of the tangent vector, say, ${z} = (z_1,z_2,\dots)$.  So, we are looking for the $z$ that makes this dot product zero. Hence, I arrive directly at $x^Tz =0$ instead of the intermediate step. I do not understand how this $x^{T} z+z^{T} x=0$ equation is reached.

Q1) Is my approach of looking for the kernel correct?
Q2) Which approach leads to this intermediate equation?

Similarly, while finding the tangent space of orthogonal Stiefel Manifold,$$
\operatorname{St}(p, n)=\left\{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}: X^{T} X=I_{p}\right\}
$$, it is stated that kernel is $
\left\{Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}: X_{0}^{T} Z+Z^{T} X_{0}=0\right\}
$. For $\operatorname{St}$ manifold case, evaluating the Jacobian like I did for the $S^{n-1}$ is cumbersome.

Q3) I am not even sure how to evaluate $DF(x)$ and looking for the corresponding $Z$ that makes $DF(X)Z$ zero.

Comment: The equation for the sphere is $x^Tx=1$, while the derivative of the map $x\mapsto x^Tx$ at a point $x$ can be calculated with the product rule to be the linear map $z\mapsto z^Tx+x^Tz=2x^Tz$. The idea for calculating the derivative of the map $X\mapsto X^TX$ (here for the Stiefel manifolds) is the same, multplication of two matrices is linear in the components of each matrix and you can use the product rule to get the result that the derivative at $X$ of that map is $Z\mapsto Z^T X+X^TZ$.

Comment: @s.harp: Thanks, that explanation helps. I have another doubt wrt Stiefel Manifolds - the books says that $\{Z: Z^TX + X^Z =0\}$ is the kernel of $DF(X)$. I tried to prove this by finding the Jacobian of the map $F:X \to X^T X$ and looking for its kernel. But, I am stuck with this approach. I want to prove that this approach gives the same answer.

Comment: $(X^TX)_{ij} = \sum_k X_{ki}X_{kj}$, so the coordinate $J^{ab}_{ij}$ of the jacobian is $\partial_{ab} (X^TX)_{ij} = \sum_k \delta_{ki,ab}X_{kj}+ \sum_k X_{ki} \delta_{kj} = X_{aj} \delta_{ib}+ X_{ai}\delta_{jb}$. Hence $\sum_{ab}J^{ab}_{ij} Z_{ab} = \sum_{a}X_{aj}Z_{ai}+ \sum_a X_{ai} Z_{aj}$, in other words $J(Z) =X^T\cdot  Z + Z^T\cdot X$. Notice that working in coordinates is a lot more unpleasant than using the usual definition of the derivative as the best affine linear approximation.

Comment: @s.harp Brilliant!! Really thankful for the answer! Just one last question: In general for matrix manifolds, for finding the tangent space, best affine Iinear approximation is easier as against trying to find out the kernel of the derivative of the map?

Comment: Usually it is more convenient to calculate the derivative using tools like the product and chain rules. Remaining "symbolic" rather than going down to coordinates is also helpful.